# HTML Creation Through For-loop Not Working Entirely

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my code:

```
let info = document.getElementById('info');
let week = document.getElementById('week');

        /*Initializer Function*/
        window.addEventListener('load', () => {
            let long;
            let lat;
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
                    long = position.coords.longitude;
                    lat = position.coords.latitude;

                    const proxy = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
                    const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/d571a1e2483b31605b94edaae84c647e/${lat},${long}`;

                    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
                            let obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                            console.log(obj);
                            document.getElementById('temperature-degree').innerHTML = obj.currently.apparentTemperature;
                            document.getElementById('location').innerHTML = obj.timezone;
                            document.getElementById('temperature-description').innerHTML = obj.currently.summary;
                            setIcons(obj.currently.icon, document.getElementById('currentDayIcon'));
                            for (let i = 0; i < obj.hourly.data.length; i++) {
                                info.innerHTML += `<div id='hour${i + 1}' class='hourly'>` + `<canvas id='hourIcon${i + 1}'></canvas>` + `<h3 id='hourTemp${i + 1}'></h3>` + `<p id='hourSummary${i + 1}'></p>` + '</div>';
                                setIcons(obj.hourly.data[i].icon, document.getElementById(`hourIcon${i + 1}`));
                                document.getElementById(`hourTemp${i + 1}`).innerHTML = obj.hourly.data[i].temperature;
                                document.getElementById(`hourSummary${i + 1}`).innerHTML = obj.hourly.data[i].summary;
                            }
                            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                                week.innerHTML += `<div id='day${i + 1}' class='daily'>` + `<canvas id='dayIcon${i + 1}'></canvas>` + `<h2 id='dayTemp${i + 1}'></h2>` + `<p id='daySummary${i + 1}'></p>` + '</div>';
                                setIcons(obj.daily.data[i].icon, document.getElementById(`dayIcon${i + 1}`));
                                document.getElementById(`dayTemp${i + 1}`).innerHTML = obj.daily.data[i].temperatureMax;
                                document.getElementById(`daySummary${i + 1}`).innerHTML = obj.daily.data[i].summary;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.open("GET", api, true);
                    xhr.send();
                });
            }
            function setIcons(icon, iconId) {
                const skycons = new Skycons({color: 'white'});
                const currentIcon = icon.replace(/-/g, '_').toUpperCase();
                skycons.play();
                return skycons.set(iconId, Skycons[currentIcon]);
            }
            ;

        });
```

...and the problem is that when it comes to the icons being loaded and displayed it's only the last one that actually displays. I don't know what the problem is because if it's successful for the last one, then it should be successful for the previous 47 since the last is the same iteration done for the 48th time. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer I gave wasn't the required answer so I've deleted it. Whatever it discussed was not the cause of problem in the code you've given.

Comment: Thank you for trying anyway. With a lot of code problems I've come across the problem has something to do with the parser or the parser just does so in a weird way. I've had to switch/upgrade IDEs for that reason.